# Jquery variable in the event selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want the function to alert the job var when clicking on an element that has an id like #rachelClone1, if this element has the class "job1".

EDIT : I did a mistake in the selector, i need something more like this, but it seemed that i cannot use descendant selector :

```
 $("#comparedChar1 #" + id1 + "boxClone .containerChar .containerJob #" + id1 + "Clone1.job1").click(function() {
    job = 1;
    alert(job);
});
```

job is already declared and id1 initialized with a string like "rachel".

Comment: Is the variable id1 initialized?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `$` in front of your selector

```
if ($(this).hasClass("job1"))
   ^^^
```

You could just use a more specific handler:

```
$('#' + id1 + 'Clone1.job1').click(function() {

})
```

Comment: It seemed to be the good way, but unfortunately i did a mistake in my selector. It has to target this precisely one :

Answer (score -1):

What is job1?
You never make an instance of job1

I guess you wanted to do something like

alert($(this).attr("class"));

OR

var job1 = $(this).attr("class");
Then 
alert(job1);

Comment: My bad, i did a mistake ; It's the job var in the alert, not job1 class